# Get web page table using LeanFT

Tags: leanft

I am trying get the table of web page however I was not able to do that.
Can any one tell me the code that gets the table from web page by using `ITable` interface in .NET with LeanFT?

Comment: what have you found online?  Do you have some code that is not working to show?

Answer (score 0):

To get a table from the web page it's just like getting any other element from the web page: use the `browser.Describe` method and provide the exact element description

```
var table = browser.Describe<ITable>(new TableDescription
{
    Id = @"someHtmlId"
});
```

If `Id` is not a property you can use, here's the entire list that you can choose from: [`TableDescription` documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.51/NetSDKReference/webframe.html#NetSDKReference/HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.Web.TableDescription.html)

Comment: Great, I got you buddy